# Cant convert sass to css after OS X 10.11 upgrade

Tags: css, ruby, terminal, sass, command

After upgrading to El Captain OS X 10.11 (open beta) I can no longer use the sass command to convert my sass back to css.

```
sass --watch input.sass:output.css
-bash sass: command not found
```

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should works:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass
```

Comment: So this installs sass in a different folder right? Will it still work globally?

Comment: Yes, the gem is installed globally. I had the same problem and this command fixes the error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (if you have homebrew installed)

```
$ brew install ruby
```

and then

```
$ sudo gem install sass
```

You can see https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1768